# jQuery - how to make a horizontal splitter to be shown at a middle even when the screen been re-sized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

first of all I'm using this plugin - [jQuery Splitter](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter) .

Now what I'm trying to do is to make the splitter been shown at the middle also when the height of the screen had changed.

In order to do so I've used the next code -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.splitter-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.splitter.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var height = $(window).height();
            $('#foo').height(height).split({ orientation: 'horizontal', limit: 50 });
            $('#b').height(height / 2);
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            var height = $(window).height();
            console.log(height);
            $('#foo').height(height).split({ orientation: 'horizontal', limit: 50 });
            $('#b').height(height/2);
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .splitter_panel .hsplitter{
            background-color:  #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <div id="a">
            <div id="x">
                <div>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dolor nisl, in suscipit justo. Donec a enim et est porttitor semper at vitae augue. Proin at nulla at dui mattis mattis. Nam a volutpat ante. Aliquam consequat dui eu sem convallis ullamcorper.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="b">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dolor nisl, in suscipit justo. Donec a enim et est porttitor semper at vitae augue. Proin at nulla at dui mattis mattis. Nam a volutpat ante. Aliquam consequat dui eu sem convallis ullamcorper. Nulla suscipit, massa vitae suscipit ornare, tellus est consequat nunc, quis blandit elit odio eu arcu. Nam a urna nec nisl varius sodales. Mauris iaculis tincidunt orci id commodo. Aliquam non magna quis tortor malesuada aliquam eget ut lacus. Nam ut vestibulum est. Praesent volutpat tellus in eros dapibus elementum. Nam laoreet risus non nulla mollis ac luctus felis dapibus. Pellentesque mattis elementum augue non sollicitudin. Nullam lobortis fermentum elit ac mollis. Nam ac varius risus. Cras faucibus euismod nulla, ac auctor diam rutrum sit amet. Nulla vel odio erat, ac mattis enim.
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, if let's say I moved the splitter to a cretin position and then I've changed the screen height, the splitter stays at it's position.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Or maybe what can I do in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK.

You can try this, though it's more of a tidy-up than a fix.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var height = $(window).height();
        console.log(height);
        $('#foo').height(height).split({ orientation:'horizontal', limit:50 });
        $('#b').height(height / 2);
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

If it works initially but not after a resize, then you have to conclude that `splitter` can't be re-invoked. Maybe apply to the author for an improvement or find a way to destroy `splitter` before re-invoking.

Comment: Well thank you for trying to help, but it seems it doesn't make the spilliter move back to the middle when the screen is re-sizing

Comment: @PESfcs, I'll leave my answer here for a while in case it helps inspire someone else. If it starts to attract negative votes, then I'll delete it. Good luck.